# Is it possible to disable the app action when our app is already released in production?

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

Is it possible to disable the app action when our app is already released in production without having to do resubmission?

I just want to make sure we can toggle it off immediately if something unexpected happens in production.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's currently not possible.  When you publish your app to Play, Assistant will ingest your App Actions configuration and will use that until you publish a new version of your app.  There is no toggle switch that disables Assistant's ability to recognize your app's config.

However, this is a good feature request, and I've love to know more about the specific situation you're trying to address or problem you're hoping to avoid, if you want to edit the question or comment further here.

Comment: Thanks for your response @doug! What I want to mitigate is if somehow in production there's a bug that causes the app action intent doesn't work or even crashes the app, at least I can disable it until the bug is fixed. However I found "Opt out of app action bootstrapping" category in [developer support](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/support/), will this disable the app action?

Comment: No, bootstrapping isn't the same thing.  If you opt out of bootstrapping, that tells Assistant not to try to guess possible actions that your app could do, even without an explicit configuration.  Once you deploy a configuration, it's on until you publish an app with the configuration removed.  App Actions will never crash your app - only your app's own code that handles incoming intents can crash the app.

Comment: If you are worried about crashes, you might want to consider putting a remote feature flag around your handling of the intent, as provided by services like Firebase Remote Config.  You'll just need to decide what to do if you don't want to handle those incoming intents.  Being launched and doing nothing would be a confusing UX.